# python - Calling function within same Class

Tags: python, function, class

Please see the sample code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]  # main list

b = [4,5,6]   #variable list nr1
c = [1,2]    #variable list nr2

class union(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def common_numbers(self, variable_list):
        self.variable_list = variable_list
        for x in self.name:
            if x in self.variable_list:
                yield(x)

    def odd_numbers(self, odds):
        self.odds = odds
        for x in self.variable_list:
            if not x % 2 == 0:
                yield x

''' I receive: builtins.AttributeError: 'union' object has no attribute 'variable_list'.'''


x = union(a)
print(list(x.odd_numbers(c)))
```

I am trying to understand how to call other function within same class. As you can see, I am trying to find odd numbers from common_numbers function.

Please understand this is sample work. I know there are plenty of solutions with or withouth using classes to get propriet result. But in this case, I don't need result, I would really appretiate if you could help me understand the calling other function within class. Sorry for my English and Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the error because you never actually define self.variable_list. It's only defined once you call common_numbers(), but you never do that. You can define it when initiating:

```
class union(object):
    def __init__(self, name, variable_list):
        self.name = name
        self.variable_list = variable_list

    def common_numbers(self):
        for x in self.name:
            if x in self.variable_list:
                yield(x)
x = union(a, b)
print list(x.odd_numbers(c))
```

or after initiating, but before calling odd_numbers:

```
class union(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def common_numbers(self):
        for x in self.name:
            if x in self.variable_list:
                yield(x)

x = union(a)
x.variable_list = b
print list(x.odd_numbers(c))
```